# Issue aligning elements in responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This might be a tough one to explain.

I seem to be running into an issue with responsive elements. I am trying to have my elements follow a 4 column structure.

In the left column it is a subheading (called 'discussion'), then the remaining 3 columns are to be a text boxes with the discussion topics. So the subheading will appear once at the top, and then depending on how many discussion topics there are will depend on how long the section is.

After this, I want another identical section called 'social' which will follow the same format.

The issue is when I try and start this new 'social' section, the subheading keeps aligning with elements in the previous 'discussion' section. I have tried using `<divs>` to create a new container but to no avail.

I'm sorry if this sounds confusing, but would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Post a https://jsfiddle.net/ , http://codepen.io/ or something with your markup and CSS

Comment: Genius idea! [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/rjwin/pen/mmjwXd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do as David Mancuso says, or add the following to your css:

```
.four-col-grid::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

If all of your rows have the same word in their classes you can catch them all by looking for a keyword in your selector like this:

```
[class*="col-grid"]::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

This will apply the ::after element to every element which has a class containing "col-grid".

Alternatively just make a utility class like "row" and add that class to every row element with this css:

```
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

That's how bootstrap and most other modern grid frameworks work.

EDIT: 
For explanation, what this does is that it creates a full width seudo element after the row element, which does not allow anything to float next to it. Thereby forcing any content floating out of place to jump down a line and begin where it's supposed to.

Comment: Great stuff. Worked great! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Between 'discussion' and 'social' add:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Add on CSS:

```
.clearfix { clear: both; }
```